# Need help in choosing units. Data processing or big data management

Tags: bigdata

I'm having dilemma of choosing between the following 2 units for my next semester. As I can only do 1 unit out of these 2, which one is more useful in terms of usefulness and industry application?

**1. Data processing.** It covers the following topics: Scala programming,
Apache spark and graph processing, data streaming algorithms and methods.

**2. Big data management.** It covers the following topics: NoSQL,
parallel data processing/distributed databases, MapReduce and Hadoop Framework,
Streaming data processing

Thank your for your attention.

I'm looking forward to replies from experienced individuals.

Comment: This isn't really the correct forum for this question as the answers will be subjective (just opinions, not facts). I would suggest asking somewhere like Quora.